# How to change meta tags on a per page basis when jquery is used to load header / footer

Tags: php, jquery

Usually my sites are built in php, using a header/footer file, and then uses variables for the meta tags, so that I can change them on a per page basis (like this http://www.jryanp.com/my-blog/creating-global-php-header-and-footer-files-for-beginners/).

But now, my developer says that is not really possible since he is using jQuery to build the site. Is there a way to accomplish this goal? Otherwise, if he needs to edit the footer (e.g. tracking code) he has to update every page on the site separately.

Comment: You can certainly amend meta tags using jQuery, eg `$('meta[name="Description"]').text('foo bar')`, however not all spiders will listen for or execute JS when reading your page and its links.

Comment: And you could put this in a header file, and then have a unique title for each page on the site?